# golang syntax error at or near "$1" in postgres using gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to find multiple users based on their name. I am using gorm as follow:

```
err := db.Where("username IN ?", []string{"name1", "name2"}).Find(&users).Error
```

But the generated query is:

`SELECT * FROM "users_customer"."user"  WHERE (username IN 'name1','name2')`

when the correct query should be:

`SELECT * FROM "users_customer"."user"  WHERE username IN ('name1','name2')`

So the error `pq: syntax error at or near "$1"`  is thrown. I use the same syntax as stated in the doc, which is `db.Where("name IN ?", []string{"jinzhu", "jinzhu 2"}).Find(&users)` but don't know why in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `IN (?)` inside your String?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Gorm` by default ad `'` this at each side and it does not add brackets `()`.

You should add it manually like this :

```
    names := []string{"name1", "name2"}

    commaSep := "'" + strings.Join(names, "', '") + "'"
    err := db.Where("username IN (?)", commaSep).Find(&users).Error
```

You can run it here : https://go.dev/play/p/ox3H2gL1yek

OR

```
err := db.Where("username IN (?)", []string{"name1", "name2"}).Find(&users).Error
```